# octavia load balancer missing policies on openstack

Tags: openstack

I am trying to integrate octavia load balancer into openstack yoga on ubuntu 22.04 lts

I have followed this guide https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/install/install-ubuntu.html

here are my install instructions https://pastebin.com/tdahmR95

It seems I am missing roles in openstack which I cannot figure out why as the test is not working

https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/contributor/guides/dev-quick-start.html

towards bottom of above page is below commands to test

```
# openstack loadbalancer create --name lb1 --vip-subnet-id private-subnet
# openstack loadbalancer show lb1
# openstack loadbalancer listener create --name listener1 --protocol HTTP --protocol-port 80 lb1
```

I error with https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-octavia/+bug/1961198 `Policy does not allow this request to be performed`

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you still need this but hopefully I can help someone. I fixed this issue by first creating the role as listed here:

https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/configuration/policy.html

`openstack role create load-balancer_admin`

and then adding my user to said role

`openstack role add --project admin --user admin load-balancer_admin`

Comment: this is an odd approach. if i create the role won't that mean i will have to create all the policies for the role? should this not be part of the installation?